Radial gradient not working as expected with typescript in react-three-drei

three version: 0.164.1
@react-three/fiber version: 8.16.6
@react-three/drei version: 9.105.6
node version: 21.7.3
npm version: 10.2.1

Problem description:
I've used the documentation found in Drei's ReadMe file to create a radial gradient; however, I'm using typescript and an error is popping up no matter what I try to do.
The error only occurs when using the GradientType.Radial
Relevant code:
<mesh ref={ref} position={[props.x, props.y, 0]}>
    <boxGeometry args={[cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize]} />
    <meshBasicMaterial>
        <GradientTexture
            stops={[0, 0.8]}
            colors={['#0090ff', 'black']}
            size={1024}
            width={1024}
            type={GradientType.Radial}
             ^
        />
    </meshBasicMaterial>
</mesh>

The error that shows when hovering over type = {GradientType.Radial} is as follows:
Type 'GradientType.Radial' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
GradientTexture.d.ts(12, 5): The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { stops: number[]; colors: string[]; attach?: string | undefined; size?: number | undefined; width?: number | undefined; type?: GradientType | undefined; innerCircleRadius?: number | undefined; outerCircleRadius?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } & ExtendedColors<...>'
(property) type?: undefined

Suggested solution:
I have searched everywhere trying to find the solution and I've found nothing. The file mentioned in the error contains the following:
// GradientTexture.d.ts
import * as React from 'react';
export declare enum GradientType {
    Linear = "linear",
    Radial = "radial"
}
type Props = {
    stops: Array<number>;
    colors: Array<string>;
    attach?: string;
    size?: number;
    width?: number;
    type?: GradientType;
    innerCircleRadius?: number;
    outerCircleRadius?: string | number;
} & JSX.IntrinsicElements['texture'];
export declare function GradientTexture({ stops, colors, size, width, type, innerCircleRadius, outerCircleRadius, ...props }: Props): React.JSX.Element;
export {};


Any help would be appreciated!
